# chandelier flickering

Tags: electrical

Brand new home built in 2017. The electrician sold me a lift for chandelier. Purchased a chandelier with 2 Leds in it. After I switch on the chandelier...after 20 min or so its starts flickering. It happens 6/10 times i switch on the chandelier. The electrician came 2-3 times ,cleaned the chandelier,the contact plates etc...works for a month and starts again. Chandelier company came and they changed the leds.... 1 month later flickers again. The chandelier company was curious and they tested the leds they took from home and was informed they worked perfectly well at their lab!!!AT this point no one has any clue whats causing the problem....
Any help diagnosing the problem is helpful....
Thanks
P.S: Not on a dimmer switch.

Comment: Are you sure it's not on a dimmer switch, or a smart switch, or some other smart x10 control? (just checking here....) Nonetheless, what else is powered from this circuit. Please list every single thing.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do the two LED bulbs (right?) behave identically?

Comment: Can you put incandescent bulbs in the chandelier?

Comment: Is there a way to upload videos/photos. I could do it so that you could see. Its a Corbett chandelier with 2 led lights.one faces ceiling and the other floor. I can definitely confirm the one facing the floor blinks. 2. There is no smart switch. 3. I don't think I can put the incandescent bulbs in there. 3.How do I know whats all on that circuit? How do I get that info...From switchboard in the basement? 4. Link to the type of chandelier I have....https://corbettlighting.hvlgroup.com/Product/213-42

Comment: The electrician sold you a lift? Is that a device for lowering/raising the chandelier? Is the lift on a remote control?

Comment: Ya, the lift is for lowering/raising the chandelier. Its not on a remote.

Comment: The lift has a switch or a key to operate it. Is it wired on the same circuit as the chandelier?  Disconnect the power source and neutral to the motor and rule out some minuscule current fluctuation the motor may be causing.  Are there other led lights in the home? If so do they ever flicker?

Comment: the lift has a key to operate. The chandelier has a 2 way switch. Both are on the same circuit. However, whent he electrician was troubleshooting few months back, he bypassed the chandelier and connected it directly. A month later the chandelier was still flickering( usually after 20 minutes of being on).